# Sqlalchemy pydantic foreignkey data

Tags: sqlalchemy, pydantic

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="items")


class ItemInDBBase(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    description: str
    owner_id: int

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True
```

I got owner_id easily. But I want also owner_name as string. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `User` class with `id`and `name`. you can add `owner_name` field for `ItemInDBBase` model.

Can you try this. Hope this helps.

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")

class Item(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="items")

class ItemInDBBase(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    description: str
    owner_id: int
    owner_name: str  # Add this field

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Function to get the values.

```
# Function to get items with owner names
def get_items_with_owner_names(db_session):
    items = db_session.query(Item).join(User).all()
    return [ItemInDBBase(
        id=item.id,
        title=item.title,
        description=item.description,
        owner_id=item.owner_id,
        owner_name=item.owner.name  # owner_name from the User relationship
    ) for item in items]
```

> when you call `get_items_with_owner_names` with a database session, it
> will return a list of `ItemInDBBase` instances with both `owner_id` and
> `owner_name` populated.